# Making a plugin only available on the front-end for the logged in super admin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, capabilities, wp-enqueue-style

I made a little plugin that enqueues 1 .js file and 1 .css file into a theme's front-end. All it does it load a grid on top of the theme so I can visualise the design.

If this plugin was activated on a live site, is it possible that only I (the super admin) can see the JS and CSS files included onto the front-end?

All I have inside the plugin file is this:

```
function load_grid() {
    wp_enqueue_style('grid_css', plugins_url('/lib/css/grid.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_script('grid_js', plugins_url('/lib/js/grid.js', __FILE__), array('jquery') );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_grid');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function load_grid() {
    if ( current_user_can( 'level_10' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style('grid_css', plugins_url('/lib/css/grid.css', __FILE__) );
        wp_enqueue_script('grid_js', plugins_url('/lib/js/grid.js', __FILE__), array('jquery') );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_grid');
```

Comment: Using `is_super_admin()` instead of `current_user_can('level_10')` would make this code a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_super_admin())
{
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_grid');
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_super_admin

Comment: Thanks but that results in - PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()